# How to speed up add/sub using GPU cuda.FloatTensor?

Tags: python, gpu, pytorch

I am trying to speed up the PSO algorithm. I have two question, want can I do to speed up the following:

1) The creation of the particles;

2) The movement equation.

> 1) `x = (xmax - xmin)*torch.rand(pop).dtype + xmin`
>
> 2) `vnext = w*torch.rand(pop).dtype + c1*torch.rand(pop).dtype*(b - x) + c2*torch.rand(pop).dtype(bg - x)`

When I use `dtype = torch.cuda.FloatTensor` is slower then using `dtype = torch.FloatTensor`.
How can I speed up the math using the `GPU`?

Comment: it looks like in these two lines there is nothing which needs to be executed in GPU, in that case why don't you do it in numpy and then convert to tensors for later operations? you won't get the advantage of GPU if you are not doing heavy operations (for which GPU is good at).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback my friend. I agree with you. What if instead of using `torch.rand(pop)`, I'd use torch.rand(pop,dim), being `dim` bigger than one. That way I would have `x` [popxdim] and the same would happen to `vnext`. In that case is possible to do each `dim`in parallel ? How?

Comment: you have nothing which requires GPU, so I think you won't be able to parallelize it using pytorch functionality. but I if you have large matrices, then you should use tensors and run it on GPU as you have matrix multiplications which are time-consuming in CPU. the best thing would be to avoid cuda unless you need it badly.

Comment: Yes, for these simple operations, the overhead associated with allocating GPU memory will probably make this entire operation take longer on GPU than on CPU. Dont't make your life hard.

Comment: @WasiAhmad thank you!

Comment: @mexmex thank you!